# MySQLDump understanding

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump

How come when I write the following line in my CMD:

`mysqldump -hHOST -uAdmin -p TestDatabase --single-transaction --routines --triggers > "C:\testdump_backup\testdump.sql"`

Then the file has this in it

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `TestDatabase ` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `TestDatabase`;
```

This is a problem for me, when I want to load all this to another database called `Database_production` like this:

`mysql -hHOST -uAdmin -p Database_production < "C:\testdump_backup\testdump.sql"`

It all works if I just use the following mysqldump line:

`mysqldump -hHOST -uAdmin -p TestDatabase > "C:\testdump_backup\testdump.sql"`

The only problem is that this doesn't contain my `stored_procedures and function`, which I need.

With the above line the file doesn't have that part with `USE TestDatabase;`, but which of the `--..` adds this part?

I need to mysqldump to copy `tables/stored_procedures/functions`, thats why I used `--single-transaction --routines --triggers`, but what am I missing here, do I even need the `--...` or?

Comment: @basha04 This works, do you actually know, if I make a extra column/table/prodecure/functions in the database I'm importing and then export the mysqldumped database into this, if it would fail/remove/overwrite the things being worked on on the "test database"

Answer (score 0):

See the options (on `mysqldump`):

```
--skip-create-options

--no-create-db
```

Comment: do you know, if I make a extra column/table/prodecure/functions in the database I'm importing and then export the mysqldumped database into this, if it would fail/remove/overwrite the things being worked on on the "test database"

Comment: @Mads - Look in the dump file (it is readable); search for `DROP`.  Or search for where the item is being `CREATEd`; there might not be a `DROP` shortly before it.  Then check the options to mysqldump relating to `DROP`.